# How to check that collection of booleans is all true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I tried to solve this problem by myself ... to no avail. My goal is to figure out whether a collection of booleans (`InRightPosition`) is true, if each `InRightPosition` is true then --> AllInRightPosition = true and destroy the `GameObject` to whom the `InRightPosition` children belong.
My code:

```
public class PanelManager : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    List slots = new List(); 
    bool allInRightPosition

  void Start()
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
         slots.Add(false);
     foreach(Transform child in transform)
     {
         int index = 0;
         do
         {
            index = Random.Range(0, 9);
         } while (slots[index]);
         slots[index] = true;
         child.localPosition = new Vector3(index/3, index%3-2,0) /* *3 */;
     }
 }
 void Update()
 {
     foreach (Transform child in transform)
     {
         if (child.GetComponent<PanelMove>() != null && child.GetComponent<PanelMove>().InRightPosition == true)
         {
             allInRightPosition = true;
             print(allInRightPosition);
         }
         else if (child.GetComponent<PanelMove>() != null &&
                  child.GetComponent<PanelMove>().InRightPosition == false)
         {
             allInRightPosition = false;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

what my code does is: if one single InRightPosition = true then AllInRightPosition = true instead of if all inRightPosition = true then AllInRightPosition = true.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: This question was cross-posted to the Unity forums: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1633878/c-checking-if-collection-of-boolean-is-true-confus.html and appears to have been answered there.

Comment: thanks for your kind gesture , Got it :-)

Comment: May I add a hopefully useful tip: if `transform` supports LINQ you could do that in one line, e.g. `allInRightPosition = !transform.Any(child => !child.GetComponent<PanelMove>().InRightPosition)`

Comment: [Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange)

Comment: if you are not getting proper answers there than you can post here ,its only limited  in stackexchange forums ,if this was posted here before than it would have been marked duplicate!

Comment: No, cross-posting is discouraged with non StackExchange sites.  *All* you have to do is: point it out yourself.  Let us know.  That's all.  Read the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't the answer I gave you [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1633878/c-checking-if-collection-of-boolean-is-true-confus.html?childToView=1633885#answer-1633885) solve your issue?

```
void Update()
 {
     allInRightPosition = true ;
     foreach (Transform child in transform)
     {
         PanelMove panelMove = child.GetComponent<PanelMove>()
         if( panelMove != null && !panelMove.InRightPosition )
         {
             allInRightPosition = false;
             break;
         }
     }
     if( allInRightPosition )
         Destroy( gameObject ) ;
 }
```

Comment: @Muhammadusman And what might that issue be? "Doctor, it hurts" is not useful information.

Comment: Great, but you still haven't described what other "issues" you're having.

Comment: actually i was having issues in Boolean value which was not working right for me so i got it after seeing that link you gave :-)